# What size particle would be attracted to this 340 ton sculpture's gravitational field?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

I know that gravity is a weak force, but this rock has mass, so it has gravity. The [Levitated Mass sculpture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levitated_Mass) is big enough to attract *something*. What is the largest particle that would "stick" to the underbelly of this sculpture because of its gravitational attraction?

I am interested in this sculpture because you can walk right under it! If the particle is big enough to see in a microscope, seems like this would be a great experiment for the *youngins*.

Comment: The problem is the rock is on earth.

Comment: To emphasize Kyle's point, the Earth is $\sim 6 \times 10^{21}\,\mathrm{mt}$ (metric tons, mind).

Comment: Earth is a rock too

Comment: Aside from that whole annoying thing about the Earth, the size of the particle has nothing to do with it.   Remember Galileo and the leaning tower of Pisa?

Comment: You don't need a large piece of matter to demonstrate gravity, neither do you need a small test particle. A simple gravitational torsion balance after Cavendish or Eotvoes gets the trick done just fine. Going small is actually counterproductive because electrostatic forces would quickly overwhelm the experiment.

Comment: Right, I get that the earth has more gravity, but the sculpture's force hasn't gone away, right? There is still a measurable amount of gravitational force to it. Also, I see the electrostatic issue now that you mention it. How did the Cavendish experiment avoid it, and can't that be replicated here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many here have noted, Earth poses a problem for your experiment.

So, let's remove it$^\dagger$.

You now have a freely floating rock in space of mass $M = 3.4\times10^8\,\mathrm{g}$ and radius $R = 330\,\mathrm{cm}$.

The escape velocity of the rock is
$$v_\mathrm{esc} = \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}},$$
where $r$ is the distance to the center of the rock, i.e. $r\gtrsim R$. This evaluates to at most $37\,\mathrm{cm}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}$.

The typical speed of a particle of mass $m$ at a gas temperature $T$ is
$$v_\mathrm{rms} = \sqrt{\frac{3 k_\mathrm{B}T}{m}},$$
where $k_\mathrm{B}$ is Boltzmann's constant. Since we've removed Earth, the temperature is given by the interplanetary medium at a distance of 1 AU from the Sun, which is of the order 100–200 K.

What this means is that the answer is not a "most massive particle", but a "least massive particle", corresponding to how close the particles can come to the rock, i.e. $r=R$. The result is
$$m = \frac{3 k_\mathrm{B} T r}{2 G M} \simeq 5\times10^{-13}\,\mathrm{g}.$$
This is not a lot, but much more massive than atoms or normal molecules. It would probably be classified as a "large dust grain"

---

$^\dagger$<sub>Removing Earth is left as an exercise for the reader.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This experiment is bound to fail, because a particle underneath the large mass will still be feeling the force of mg of the earth. The attraction of the large mass will have an upward force of (m_1xm_2/r^2)xG .

[image: gravitational constant]

From the value of the gravitational constant one sees that the equivalent "g" for the attraction of the levitating mass is very small for 340 tons to overcome the force of earth gravity.